# Substracting seconds in date MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to substract 5 seconds to a date so I have "Select Now() from Table". I obtain 2011-08-30 18:31:37.0. However, the expected output is 2011-08-30 18:**31**:32.0. What would be the best approach to substract seconds to a date??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 5 SECOND`
or
`SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND)`
whatever you like more.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has built in date functions that are fast.  Use select Date_Sub(Now(), interval 5 second);

HTH